# DAX RANKX formula to skip ties properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot, dax

I have (video) games collection table [GC], with 'title, 'series' and various score columns (aggregate, experts, users...).

The table in PowerPivot view:
[image: table in PowerPivot view]

I can't figure out a formula that properly skips ties, if there are rows with the same 'series' and 'average score' values. Above, you can see, that "Elder Scrolls" series should be ranked 38 instead of 37.